# how can retrieve selected value from many2one field in tryton

Tags: python, tryton

I have to create a many2one or Selection field called Category and an other field called echelon. For one category we associate many echelons. This like the example of choosing the country and for this country we fill an other field by subdivisions associated. my code:

---

```
categoryy=fields.Many2One("grh.category","Category")
ech = fields.Many2One("grh.echelon",'echelon', depends=[ 'categoryy'])

@fields.depends('ech', 'categoryy')
def on_change_categoryy(self):
    if (self.ech
            and self.ech.echeloncategory != self.categoryy):
        return {'ech': None}
    return {}
```

---

```
from trytond.model import ModelView,ModelSQL,fields

__all__ = ['echelon']


class echelon(ModelView,ModelSQL):
    '''echelon'''
    __name__ = "grh.echelon"
    echeloncategory=fields.Many2One("grh.category","echelonofcategory")
    echelon=fields.Char("Echelon")
```

---

```
from trytond.model import ModelView,ModelSQL,fields
from trytond.pool import Pool

__all__ = ['category']


class category(ModelView,ModelSQL):
    '''category'''
    __name__ = "grh.category"
    category=fields.Char("category")
    echelons=fields.One2Many("grh.echelon","echeloncategory","Category echelons")
```

---

i don't know why the 'ech' field is showing all the echelons

help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a domain clause to restrict the available options on your `ech` field. You can find the full reference of domains on:

http://doc.tryton.org/3.2/trytond/doc/topics/domain.html?highlight=domain

Also you must use PYSON to get the current value of the category, so you will end up with something like:

```
from trytond.pyson import Eval
ech = fields.Many2One("grh.echelon",'echelon', 
    domain=[
        ('category', '=', Eval('category', -1)),
    depends=['categoryy'])
```

You can find an introduction about PYSON on:

http://doc.tryton.org/3.2/trytond/doc/topics/pyson.html